# Test for substrings with diacritics in strings

Tags: python, string, substring, diacritics

I'm testing in Python if certain string contains something as follows

```
if substr in str:
  do_something()
```

The problem is when substr contains letter with diacritics and other non usual characters.
How would you recommend to do tests with such letters?

thank you

Comment: perhaps update your question with an example to showcase the problem?

Comment: @Fredrik : The correct example is in Rafal answer.

Comment: but as @Rafal states, it *just* works. what doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know of any problems specific to diacritics in Python. The following works for me:

```
 u"ł" in u"źdźbło"
 >>> True
```

Edit:

```
u"ł" in u"źdźblo"
>>> False
```

The matching is exact. If diacritics-insensitive matching is what you want, specify this in your question and see Fredrik's answer.

Edit2: Yes, for string literals containing non-ascii chars you need to specify the encoding in the source file. Something like this should work:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

Comment: Dowgird : And what if I want to test `in title`? can I write `in u"title`?

Comment: this writes `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc5' in file fds on line 67, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`

Answer (score 0):

Use the solution outlined in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string/518232#518232) to remove all diacritics prior to the testing.